# Cómo leer el contenido de un iframe creado desde javascript y no insertado como html

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un iframe y a su vez un blob que contiene una estructura básica de html y que incluye un texto, ese texto me interesa obtenerlo posteriormente usando *contentWindow* pero sucede que me da error al esperar que se cargue el archivo usando *onload*.

Pero si yo hago el mismo proceso llamando a un iframe ya establecido en el html si funciona... ¿Qué puedo hacer para que lea el contenido cargado sin tener que crear un iframe en el html?

```js
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

// document.querySelector("iframe"); así si funciona

let hello_blob = "<html><head></head><body>¡Hola!</body></html>";

let hello_blob_create = new Blob([hello_blob], {

  type: "text/html"

});

if (hello_blob_create) {

let hello_blob_create_url = URL.createObjectURL(hello_blob_create);
hello_blob.src = hello_blob_create_url;


hello_blob.onload = () => {

let hello_blob_get_text = hello_blob.contentWindow.document.body.innerText;

alert(hello_blob_get_text);

}


}
```

Comment: Te falta el `=` entre `onload` y `()`.

Comment: Tienes algún código HTML integrado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blob tiene una función asíncrona `text()` para convertir en texto, luego puedes hacer uso de `DOMparser`, te dejo un código con comentarios

```js
let hello_blob = "<html><head></head><body>¡Hola!</body></html>";

let hello_blob_create = new Blob([hello_blob], {

  type: "text/html"

});
//=================================================


//transformamos el blob a text
hello_blob_create.text().then(value => {

  //usamos DOMParser para convertir el texto a documento
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, "text/html");

  //este documento se maneja igual que el DOM principal
  //puedes hacer de todo como:
  
  console.log(doc.body.innerText);
  
  //o tambien
  console.log(doc.querySelector("body").innerText);

});
```

Comment: No funciona si el html contiene un javascript, no carga el contenido del javascript

Comment: se me había ido ese dato... Al igual te doy los puntos por haber respondido inicialmente.